# jQuery UI, sortable, can I determine that element from X position went to Y?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

all I have is this example here: http://jqueryui.com/sortable/ now I want to have a "magic" event that tells me that, for example I move item5 to item2 and it tells me that "5 moved to 2" position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No I think there is no "magic"-event according to the api but this would be one way to do this:

```
var startArray, stopArray;
$("#sortable").sortable({
    start: function(){ //save items in array before they are sorted
        startArray = $(this).sortable('toArray');
    },
    beforeStop: function(){ //save new sortorder of items
        stopArray = $(this).sortable('toArray');
    },
    update: function(){ //if the dom is changed, check the differences
        $.each(stopArray, function(index, value){
            if(startArray[index] !== value){ //if the values don't fit, they are changed
                console.log(value + ' is now on position ' + (index+1));
            }
        });

    }
});
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/n3o9cfLk/1/)**

**Reference**

[event-start](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-start)

[event-beforeStop](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-beforeStop)

[event-update](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-update)

[.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)